# Cannot find symbol in same package and directory

Tags: java, compilation, symbols

I have two classes, Offering and Course. They are both in the same package and the same directory.

Offering.java:

```
package assignment02;

public class Offering implements Comparable<Offering> {
    private Course course;
    private int CRN;
    private int semester;

    public Offering(Course course, int CRN, int semester) {
        this.course = course;
        this.CRN = CRN;
        this.semester = semester;
    }

    public int getNumCredits() {
        return course.getNumCredits;
    }

    public int getCRN() {
        return CRN;
    }

    public int getSemester() {
        return semester;
    }

    public int compareTo(Offering other) {
        if(other == null) return - 1;
        return semester - other.semester;
    }
}
```

Course.java:

```
package assignment02;

public class Course {
    private String name;
    private String rubric;
    private String number;
    private int numCredits;

    public Course(String name, String rubric, String number, int numCredits) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rubric = rubric;
        this.number = number;
        this.numCredits = numCredits;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRubric() {
        return rubric;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public int getNumCredits() {
        return numCredits;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile Offering, I get the errors:

```
D:\CS 140\assignment02>javac Offering.java
Offering.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    private Course course;
            ^
   symbol:   class Course
   location: class Offering
```

and

```
Offering.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    public Offering(Course course, int CRN, int semester) {
                    ^
   symbol:   class Course
   location: class OfferingOffering.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
```

I know that the error means the compiler is unable to do anything with 'Course,' but I don't really know why. I also know that it will end up being something incredibly obvious, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `D:\CS 140>javac assignment02\Offering.java`?

Comment: Did you compile Course.java first?

Comment: Change directories to the parent directory and try `javac assignment02\Course.java assignment02\Offering.java`.  You should also then be able to compile the classes individually.  The compiler is trying to find the `Course` class in the `assignment02` package from your CURRENT location

Comment: @John For anything more than a standalone single class (single file) project, I'd recommend that you use an IDE like IntelliJ.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change directories to the parent directory of `assignment02`.  You should then be able to use

```
javac assignment02\Course.java assignment02\Offering.java
```

or

```
javac assignment02\Course.java 
javac assignment02\Offering.java
```

or even

```
javac assignment02\*.java
```

The compiler is is looking for the `Course` class in the `assignment02` package FROM your current directory (so when you're in the `assignment02` directory, it's effectively trying to look in `assignment02/assignment02`, which obviously isn't right).

While this will correct your current problem you will then get the following error:

```
assignment02\Offering.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable getNumCredits
location: class assignment02.Course
    return course.getNumCredits;
                 ^
1 error
```

Which will need to corrected.

Comment: Well, you solved the first problem, thanks! Now I'm getting that error, but when I'm looking at Offering.java, I fixed the problem. The compiler is still reading the wrong version though. I did save Offering.java after I fixed that problem

Comment: Try deleting the `.class` files

Comment: Nope, still not recognizing the changes. This is weird

Comment: I'd make sure the files you are editing and the files you are compiling are the same thing then

Comment: Once I correct for the second error, it works fine for me

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know what's going on. I add the parenthesis, but the error the compiler gives doesn't have them

Comment: Whatever it was, it decided to work this time around. Thanks a lot for the help, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can also compile using the "-classpath" argument, with its value set to the parent directory, like this:

```
javac -classpath .. Offering.java
```

Comment: And you can also abbreviate that switch to "-cp".

Answer (score -1):

You need to compile Course.java first—Offering.java depends on it because you referenced it. Also,

```
public int getNumCredits() {
    return course.getNumCredits;
}
```

should be

```
public int getNumCredits() {
    return course.getNumCredits();
}
```

Comment: Course.java is compiled and I'm still getting the same error